# Save the data values from jQuery textbox

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am working on an asp.net page where I am saving user input into my database using TextBox e.g *`***<asp:TextBox ID="code" runat="server" Width="155px"></asp:TextBox>***`* 
in this case I'm getting the ID of the TextBox as "code" so i can capture the values from that TextBox. Now i have a jQuery texbox ***`<input type="text" id="date" required="required"/>`*** where "date" is jQuery function ID. Which attribute or ID should i use to capture the user input and save them into my database using this **`<input type="text" id="date" required="required"/>`** textbox..?

Comment: your question is not clear. Please provide your code and phrase it properly

Comment: this is vague and uses confusing terminology. Post the relevant code please.

Answer (score 1):

you can change your plain textbox to asp textbox

```
<asp:TextBox Id="date" runat="server" required="required" />
```

if not than you can get values of plain Html elements in code behind.

1. Write a function to set the value of "date" textbox to a  hidden
   field
2. Than capture the value of hiddenfield in your code behind

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

Why not simply turn that field into a asp.net control as well?

Would be:

```
<asp:TextBox Id="date" runat="server" required="required" />
```

It will be rendered as a input type="text" to the browser anyway and should work just fine.

In order to find the control (since ASP.NET sometimes have the odd interest in prefixing controls) you can just use `$find` in your script. Or, as someone pointed out, use class selectors (i.e assign a `CssClass` attribute to your TextBox) and use that as selector in your jQuery code.

That way the date value will be available both to server side operations and client side.

Comment: @Inno if an answer worked please remember to mark it as the accepted answer. If more than one worked, pick the best quality answer.

Answer (score 0):

you can use Asp.Net textbox as jquery datepicker, just use class selector to convert into jquery ui date picker